# Paste rows from one sheet to another when condition is met in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro with all tasks I have to do to generate a report, currently I need merge new data from the new sheet to the original. Some sort of JOIN if we could call it like that.

In the `srcWorkbook` we have things like address, who was in charge in that time and a date/id timestamp. In the `outWorkbook` there's vendor personal data and such.

[Output table / New data table / Output table (after running macro)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beuoj.png)

To merge the both sheets I want to match `id_date` and `id_hr` in both files so if `srcWorkbook` and `outWorkbook` id's match, grab `srcWorkbook` row and paste it on the side of the `outWorkbook`.

I've tried to do a for / if statement which reads apparently but it doesn't paste the new rows. I also tried a VLOOKUP but I'd rather stick with basic statements for future modifications.

```
Sub popularSubG()
'File calling here and index variables
'Cells
' cell Src
Dim cellSrcPerPro As Long
Dim cellSrcIDHR As Long

' cell Out
Dim cellOutPerPro As Long
Dim cellOutIDHR As Long

For indexRowSrc = 2 To indexLastRowSrc
    cellSrcPerPro = srcWorkbook.Cells(indexRowSrc, "A").Value
    cellSrcIDHR = srcWorkbook.Cells(indexRowSrc, "B").Value
    
    cellOutPerPro = outWorkbook.Cells(indexRowSrc, "A").Value
    cellOutIDHR = outWorkbook.Cells(indexRowSrc, "B").Value
    
    If cellSrcPerPro = cellOutPerPro & cellSrcIDHR = cellDestinoIDHR Then
        indexRowOut = indexRowOut + 1
        srcWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, "C").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=outWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0)
    End If
Next indexRowSrc
MsgBox "Sub ended"
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot use **&** instead of the **AND** operator.

Comment: Note also that you can't copy an entire row and paste it starting in column O. You shouldn't need to copy the entire row. There are questions here on SO showing how to find the last column to limit the range being copied.

Comment: But the outSheet original data have columns until "O"